# Return custom value(String) from method if this method is void using Mokito testing

Tags: java, testing, junit, return

tried

```
doAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
                @Override
                public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {               
                    return "String";
                }
            }).when(object).voidMethod();
            Assert.assertEquals("String",object.voidMethod());
```

and

```
doReturn("String").when(object.voidMethod())
```

but this not works because voidMethod() is void. Is any variants not to use doThrow()?
I want to emulate answer of some service this void method sends some data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock/test method that returns void, possibly in Mockito](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382955/how-to-mock-test-method-that-returns-void-possibly-in-mockito)

Comment: Why would you want a void method to return something anyway? What do you test by doing so?

Comment: I want to emulate answer of some service this void method sends some data

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to ever make a method return something (via Mockito), if the signature of that method says it returns void. I think it's pretty much impossible.