# Using Mockito with multiple calls to the same method with the same arguments

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

Is there a way to have a stubbed method return different objects on subsequent invocations? I'd like to do this to test nondeterminate responses from an `ExecutorCompletionService`. i.e. to test that irrespective of the return order of the methods, the outcome remains constant.

The code I'm looking to test looks something like this.

```
// Create an completion service so we can group these tasks together
ExecutorCompletionService<T> completionService =
        new ExecutorCompletionService<T>(service);

// Add all these tasks to the completion service
for (Callable<T> t : ts)
    completionService.submit(request);

// As an when each call finished, add it to the response set.
for (int i = 0; i < calls.size(); i ++) {
    try {
        T t = completionService.take().get();
        // do some stuff that I want to test
    } catch (...) { }        
}
```

Answer (score 346, accepted):

You can do that using the [`thenAnswer`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenAnswer(org.mockito.stubbing.Answer)) method (when chaining with [`when`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#when(T))):

```
when(someMock.someMethod()).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
    private int count = 0;

    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        if (count++ == 1)
            return 1;

        return 2;
    }
});
```

Or using the equivalent, static [`doAnswer`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer(org.mockito.stubbing.Answer)) method:

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    private int count = 0;

    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        if (count++ == 1)
            return 1;

        return 2;
    }
}).when(someMock).someMethod();
```

Comment: This answer helped me a lot because `doAnswer()`/`thenAnswer()` do not allow chaining multiple calls as `doReturn()`/`thenReturn()` do and I needed to compute something and not just return a different value. Creating an anonymous `Answer` object with a private `count` variable was what did the trick for me.

Comment: Keep in mind that these are not equivalent when `someMethod()` returns `void`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-mock-void-methods-with-mockito) answer for more details.

Comment: Works as a charm.

Comment: @LucioPaiva Where do you get the information, that you can not chain "doAnswer" calls with other calls? Is this a known bug, feature or something else?

Comment: @KFleischer You CAN chain `doAnswer` calls, and also mix them with other `do...` calls.  You can also chain `thenAnswer` calls, and mix them with other `then...` calls.  I believe Lucio has made a mistake.

Answer (score 955):

How about

```
when( method-call ).thenReturn( value1, value2, value3 );
```

You can put as many arguments as you like in the brackets of thenReturn, provided they're all the correct type.  The first value will be returned the first time the method is called, then the second answer, and so on.  The last value will be returned repeatedly once all the other values are used up.

Comment: This will work with a mock, but not with a spy. If you need to prevent calling the original method you need doAnswer(...).when(someSpy).someMethod(...).

Comment: @Yuri - not quite.  You don't need `doAnswer` or to write an `Answer` in the case that you mention.  You can just use `doReturn(...).when(someSpy).someMethod(...)`.  It seems reasonable to assume that Emma is interested in mocks, rather than spies, but I guess I could add something to my answer to spell this out.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem lets say for the first call I want to return a value and for the second call I want to throw an Exception. How can this be done?

Comment: @Rito Please read Volodymyr's answer or Raystorm's answer. They both cover that case.

Comment: Wow, have wasted almost 3 hours debugging HashSet, Spring beans...others, in a loop of 3, thenReturn was giving the same mock object, which results in same hashCode in HashSet, which results in HashSet having 1 element instead of 3 elements, which results in test case failures due to assertion. Thanks.

Comment: "Thank You" I really want to stress "thank you" again:D

Comment: Thanks! Works with different kinds of answers as well:
`when(foo).thenThrow(new RuntimeException(), new RuntimeException().thenReturn(null);`

Answer (score 251):

As [previously pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30218915/659354) almost all of the calls are chainable.

So you could call

```
when(mock.method()).thenReturn(foo).thenReturn(bar).thenThrow(new Exception("test"));

//OR if you're mocking a void method and/or using spy instead of mock

doReturn(foo).doReturn(bar).doThrow(new Exception("Test").when(mock).method();
```

More info in [Mockito's Documenation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/index.html?org/mockito/Mockito.html).

Comment: Very helpful!

What would happen the 4th time `mock.method` was called in this example? I want something like, return foo the first time but return bar for ALL the rest.

Comment: Each additional invocation on the mock will return the last 'thenReturn' or the last 'thenThrow'   Very useful

Comment: Thank you for the great and simple instructions. Never knew this until now. I was struggling to find how to get back two different results on two identical call. Save me tons of time.

Comment: Excellent solution! Using this.

Answer (score 93):

Almost all of the calls are chainable:

```
doReturn(null).doReturn(anotherInstance).when(mock).method();
```

Answer (score 54):

## BDD style:

```
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
        ...

        given(yourMock.yourMethod()).willReturn(1, 2, 3);
```

## Classic style:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
        ...

        when(yourMock.yourMethod()).thenReturn(1, 2, 3);
```

## Explicit style:

```
        ...

        when(yourMock.yourMethod())
            .thenReturn(1)
            .thenReturn(2)
            .thenReturn(3);
```

## Depending on an arg

**Option #1**

Suppose we have 2 args, and check the size of the 2nd (list) arg:

```
        ...

        when(yourMock.yourMethod(any(), anyList()))
             .thenAnswer(args -> ((List) args.getArgument(1)).size() < 2
                                 ? 1
                                 : 3);
```

args are Objects, so we have to cast an arg to our type. I cast ^^^ to `(List)` in my case.

**Option #2 (BDD)**

```
        ...

        given(yourMock.yourMethod(any(), anyList()))
             .willAnswer(args -> ((List) args.getArgument(1)).size() < 2
                                 ? 1
                                 : 3);
```

Answer (score 5):

I've implemented a `MultipleAnswer` class that helps me to stub different answers in every call. Here the piece of code:

```
private final class MultipleAnswer<T> implements Answer<T> {

    private final ArrayList<Answer<T>> mAnswers;

    MultipleAnswer(Answer<T>... answer) {
        mAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
        mAnswers.addAll(Arrays.asList(answer));
    }

    @Override
    public T answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        return mAnswers.remove(0).answer(invocation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you initialize that object in a short, simple and readable way?

Answer (score 4):

> doReturn( value1, value2, value3 ).when( method-call )

Comment: Do you mean `doReturn(value1, value2, value3).when(mock).methodCall()` perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a dynamic list of values you can use [`AdditionalAnswers.returnsElementsOf`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#returnsElementsOf-java.util.Collection-):

```java
import org.mockito.AdditionalAnswers;

when(mock.method()).thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsElementsOf(myListOfValues));
```

Answer (score 3):

Related to @[Igor Nikolaev]'s answer from 8 years ago, using an `Answer` can be simplified somewhat using a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) available in Java 8.

```
when(someMock.someMethod()).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
    doStuff();
    return;
});
```

or more simply:

```
when(someMock.someMethod()).thenAnswer(invocation -> doStuff());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `LinkedList` and an [`Answer`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.4/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html). Eg

```java
MyService mock = mock(MyService.class);
LinkedList<String> results = new LinkedList<>(List.of("A", "B", "C"));
when(mock.doSomething(any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> results.removeFirst());
```

Or perhaps

```java
LinkedList<Answer<String>> answers = new LinkedList<>();
answers.add(invocation -> "A");
answers.add(invocation -> "B");
answers.add(invocation -> { throw new Exception(); });
when(mock.doSomething(any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> results.removeFirst().apply(invocation));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly related to the question. But wanted to put this in the same chain.

If trying to verify the same method call with multiple arguments, you can use the below times feature by Mockito. You don't need it if you are not verifying.

Mockito.verify(method, times(n)).methoscall();

Here is 'n' is the number of times the mock is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Following can be used as a common method to return different arguments on different method calls. Only thing we need to do is we need to pass an array with order in which objects should be retrieved in each call.

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <Mock> Answer<Mock> getAnswerForSubsequentCalls(final Mock... mockArr) {
    return new Answer<Mock>() {
       private int count=0, size=mockArr.length;
       public Mock answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws throwable {
           Mock mock = null;
           for(; count<size && mock==null; count++){
                mock = mockArr[count];
           }

           return mock;    
       } 
    }
}
```

Ex. `getAnswerForSubsequentCalls(mock1, mock3, mock2);` will return mock1 object on first call, mock3 object on second call and mock2 object on third call. 
Should be used like `when(something()).doAnswer(getAnswerForSubsequentCalls(mock1, mock3, mock2));`
This is almost similar to `when(something()).thenReturn(mock1, mock3, mock2);`

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example in BDD style which is pretty simple and clear

```
given(carRepository.findByName(any(String.class))).willReturn(Optional.empty()).willReturn(Optional.of(MockData.createCarEntity()));
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be basic/obvious, but if like me you are trying to mock multiple calls for a method that is called unknown number of times per call to method to be tested, for example:

```java
public String method(String testArg) {
    //...
    while(condition) {
        someValue = someBean.nestedMethod(); // This is called unknown number of times
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

You can do something like:

```java
@Test
public void testMethod() {
    mockNestedMethodForValue("value1");
    assertEquals(method("arg"), "expected1");
    mockNestedMethodForValue("value2");
    assertEquals(method("arg"), "expected2");
    mockNestedMethodForValue("value3");
    assertEquals(method("arg"), "expected3");
}

private void mockNestedMethodForValue(String value) {
    doReturn(value).when(someBeanMock).nestedMethod();
}
```