# How to mock a method which is called twice and argument of second method call is output of first method call using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

```
public List<Object> getDummyData(String testString ) {      
    final List<String> result1 = utility.getData(testString);
    final List<String> result2 = utility.getData(result1.get(0).split(~)[0]);       
    // Processing of result2 and few more method calls      
    return someListOfObject;
}
```

I need to mock the method having above method calls. When I go with below code:

```
MainApp mock= Mockito.mock(MainApp.class);
List<String> mockList = Mockito.mock(ArrayList.class);
doReturn(mockList).when(mock).getData("str");
```

I am getting IndexOutOfBoundsException while running the test case at second method call.

Comment: Any further feedback? Is there anything I could add to make you consider upvote/accept?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that exception is that line:

```
 utility.getData(result1.get(0).split(~)[0]);
```

You want to **split** on the result from your first call. 
But you didn't specify anything about that mock! And when you don't specify anything, then mockito will just return dummy/empty/null data when methods are called on that mock.

And you don't have to. You **absolutely** do **not** mock a list object. You simply create a list that fits your test; like

```
List<String> dummyList = Arrays.asList("whatever", "strings", "you need");
```

Just to make that very clear: *mocking* is your **last** resort. You **only** use it in order to get control over objects you need to control; and that can't be controlled any other way.

And a **list** is super-easy to control: by creating a list that contains what you need to be in that list.

The other part of your question: you can instruct Mockito easily to return different results when the same method is called repeatedly; for example like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088179/using-mockito-with-multiple-calls-to-the-same-method-with-the-same-arguments).

Comment: Thaks for the replay. I got your point but still in this case even if I create a list as you have suggested how the method call i.e. getData will get differentiate? `MainApp mock= Mockito.mock(MainApp.class);
List<String> dummyList = Arrays.asList("whatever", "strings", "you need");
doReturn(dummyList).when(mock).getData("str")`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an error is that `Mockito.mock(ArrayList.class)` has not values so when `get(0)` you get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Instead you should be putting data in a real list.

```
MainApp mock= Mockito.mock(MainApp.class);
List<String> resultA = Arrays.asList("some~value", "some~other~value");
doReturn(resultA).when(mock).getData("str");
List<String> resultB = Arrays.asList("other value", "more other values");
doReturn(resultB).when(mock).getData("some");
```

While the above would work I would suggest using matchers for the mocking and then verify the correct results. The reason being that you will get better error messages if the test fails.

```
MainApp mock= Mockito.mock(MainApp.class);

// Mock multiple return values
Mockito.when(mock.getData(anyString())
  .thenReturn(Arrays.asList("some~value", "some~other~value"))
  .thenReturn(Arrays.asList("other value", "more other values"));

List<SomeObjects> result = getDummyData("some-arg");
Mockito.verify(mock).getData("some-arg"); //Verify correct calls
Mockito.verify(mock).getData("some");

// verify result
```