# How to capture same object multiple times in Mockito argument captor

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I was writing a Junit to test a scenario where an object changes its variables and saves it into the database 2 times. The `argumentCaptor` is invoked in save operation. The `getAllValues()` is returning two records. But both values are referenced to the same last capture record.

ImplimentationClass.java

```java
 ...

myObj.setVariable(oneValue);
saveMyObj(myObj);
myObj.setVariable(otherValue);
saveMyObj(myObj);

...

saveMyObj(MyObject myObj){
repository.save(myObj);
}
```

ImplimentationClassTest.java

```
private ImplimentationClass underTest ;

@Mock
private Repository mockRepository;

@Before
public void setup(){
  initMocks(this);
  underTest = new ImplimentationClassTest();
}

@Test
public void test(){
ArgumentCaptor<MyObject> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyObject.class);
MyObject obj = new MyObject(value);
underTest.implementedMethod(obj);
verify(mockRepository, times(2)).save(captor.capture());
assertEquals(oneValue, captor.getAllValues().get(0).getVariable()); //failing here -getting otherValue
assertEquals(otherValue, captor.getAllValues().get(1).getVariable());

}
```

Any idea how to capture same object multiple times?

Comment: I stumble upon the very same problem. I change the same variable during runtime, so that the captor references the same. The debugger shows it well: Although captor.getAllValues() correctly contains 2 objects, both are actually the same instance and thus have the same values etc. I search for a solution within Mockito, but it seems there is none...

Answer (score 1):

The problem from your test originates from this piece of code.

```
myObj.setVariable(oneValue);
saveMyObj(myObj);
myObj.setVariable(otherValue);
saveMyObj(myObj);
```

Once you change the `variable` inside of `myObj` you change it for all references. Note that the `ArgumentCaptor` does not make a deep copy of `myObj`. 
So you will end up with two references to `myObj`, which only has the latest state.

To avoid this you might want to pass a different instance to the second call.

---

Another alternative might be to use `doAnswer` instead and check the correctness of the paramter inside that method.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8088220/11514534) for an example.