# Mockito - when ... thenReturn multiple times by passing a list of expected values

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

Why Mockito does not support a collection in `thenReturn` method?

I want

```
// mockObject.someMethod() returns an instance of "Something".
// Want to achieve that call mockObject.someMethod the first time returns Something_1, call mockObject.someMethod the second time returns Something_2, call mockObject.someMethod the third time returns Something_3, ...
List<Something> expectedValues = ...;
when(mockObject.someMethod()).thenReturn(expectedValues);
```

because the count of `expectedValues` is arbitrary.

Comment: Does mockObject.someMethod() return a List<Something> ?

Comment: @SteveBenett No, it returns a `Something` object. Updated the question.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33698670/9985287). I think it is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @MensurQulami This only works if I know the count of expected values. What if I don't know the count of expected values?

Comment: I mean if you want to pass a List as an argument, shouldn't you know the exact number of expected values? I am not sure I understood what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method  `thenReturn` supports varargs but no Collections:

```
Mockito.when(mockObject.someMethod()).thenReturn(something1, something2, ...);

OR

Mockito.when(mockObject.someMethod()).thenReturn(something, arrayOfSomething);
```

An alternative is to chain the `thenReturn` calls:

```
Mockito.when(mockObject.someMethod()).thenReturn(something1).thenReturn(something2);
```

Both will return `something1` on the first call of `mockObject.someMethod()` and `something2` on the second call etc.

Comment: The `Mockito.when(mockObject.someMethod()).thenReturn(something, arrayOfSomething);` is exactly what I want. Thanks!