# Okhttp3 - How to define a specific Request in an Okhttp3 Client

Tags: java, mockito, okhttp

I've got a recursive method which uses `okhttp3` to make consecutive paging requests to an endpoint until an attribute is no longer there. My tests run that simulate the last call in the process but I'm having trouble working through a 2 step iteration.

How do I define a specific ohkttp3.Request in the newCall() method so it doesn;t throw a NullPointer each time? My code/test is below for reference.

**Error:** java.lang.NullPointerException

**Recursive Method**

```
public JSONArray recursiveMethod(JSONArray array, String authCode, String requestUrl) {
        String nextPageAtt = "newPage";
        String newPage = null;
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(requestUrl)
                .get()
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Authorization", authCode)
                .build();
                
        try {
            //Problem child
            okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (response.code() == SUCCESS_CODE && response.body() != null) {

                //Add JSON data to array 
                
                //if "newPage" attribute in response, set it here
                //only present when page != last page
                
            } else {
            }
        }
        //"newPage" attribute won't be present on the last page of data"
        if (newPage != null) {
            recursiveMethod(array, authCode, baseUrl + newPage);
        }
        return array;
    }
```

**Test Method**

```
@Test
void recursiveMethodNonewPage() throws IOException {
        JSONArray emptyArray = new JSONArray();
    
        final Response successResponse = new Response.Builder()
                .request(new Request.Builder().url("https://localhost:8080/getData").build()) //"newPage" not there (last call)
                .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
                .code(SUCCESS_CODE).message("").body(
                        ResponseBody.create(
                                MediaType.parse("application/json"),
                                "/////JSON/////"
                        ))
                .build();
                
        when(remoteCall.execute()).thenReturn(successResponse);
        
        //this works when I pass "any()" but a java.lang.NullPointerException is thrown when I enter a specific Request
        when(mockClient.newCall(any())).thenReturn(remoteCall);
        
        //******Issue******
        //Need to pass a specific request on in order to simulate multiple recursive iterations
        /*Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(https://localhost:8080/getData)
                .get()
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Authorization", authCode)
                .build();*/
                
        //Throws Null
        //when(mockClient.newCall(request))).thenReturn(remoteCall);
        
        JSONArray newArray = getDataUtil.recursiveMethod(emptyArray, authCodeSuccess, "https://localhost:8080/getData");
        assertEquals(4, newArray.length());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8395685/2573297

```
when( method-call ).thenReturn( value1, value2, value3 );
```

**Working Test**

```
@Test
void recursiveMethodNonewPage() throws IOException {
        JSONArray emptyArray = new JSONArray();
    
        final Response pageOne = new Response.Builder()
                .request(new Request.Builder().url("https://localhost:8080/getData").build())
                .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
                .code(SUCCESS_CODE).message("").body(
                        ResponseBody.create(
                                MediaType.parse("application/json"),
                                "/////JSON/////"
                        ))
                .build();
                
        final Response pageTwo = new Response.Builder()
                .request(new Request.Builder().url("https://localhost:8080/getData").build())
                .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
                .code(SUCCESS_CODE).message("").body(
                        ResponseBody.create(
                                MediaType.parse("application/json"),
                                "/////JSON/////"
                        ))
                .build();
        
        when(mockClient.newCall(any())).thenReturn(remoteCall);
        when(remoteCall.execute()).thenReturn(pageOne, pageTwo);
        
        JSONArray newArray = getDataUtil.recursiveMethod(emptyArray, authCodeSuccess, "https://localhost:8080/getData");
        assertEquals(4, newArray.length());
    }
```