# Mockito verify doesn't match multiple stub

Tags: mockito

It seems that, when I use thenReturn like this:

when(abc.call()).thenReturn(a).thenReturn(b),

I expect:

verify(abc, times(2)).call()

instead, the method seems only get called once, I am a little confused(my test work as expected, the mock seems return the value I expected), but for the invocation times, I don't know if I am getting the wrong result, or it's a expected behavior of the Mockito?

Answer (score 0):

when() is mocking the abc.call() method which has to produce a certain return type. If the method is called once, it will return the value also once, so the stubbing for method invocation is done only once hence the verify only recognizes one call.

You need to customize your function so that the stub(abc.call()) gets called more than once.

You can follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088179/using-mockito-with-multiple-calls-to-the-same-method-with-the-same-arguments) for implementing multiple stubs

Comment: I am sure that I have got all the mock values I want, I can see my test have received all the mock values, but still mockito tell me the method only get called once.

Comment: yes thats because the method in which your mock object is written is getting invoked once, even if you pass multiple values the mock call in the method scope remains one only