# Mockito test a void method throws an exception

Tags: java, exception, mocking, mockito

I have a method with a `void` return type. It can also throw a number of exceptions so I'd like to test those exceptions being thrown. All attempts have failed with the same reason:

> The method when(T) in the type Stubber is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Any ideas how I can get the method to throw a specified exception?

```
doThrow(new Exception()).when(mockedObject.methodReturningVoid(...));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make mock to void methods with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-make-mock-to-void-methods-with-mockito)

Answer (score 1134, accepted):

The parentheses are poorly placed.

You need to use:

```
doThrow(new Exception()).when(mockedObject).methodReturningVoid(...);
                                          ^
```

and **NOT** use:

```
doThrow(new Exception()).when(mockedObject.methodReturningVoid(...));
                                                                   ^
```

This is explained in [the documentation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing_with_exceptions)

Comment: @edwardmlyte This Mockito inconsistency is one of the reasons I've switch to [MoxieMocks](https://code.google.com/p/moxiemocks/wiki/MockingLibraryComparison)

Comment: @clement both can be used: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#5. Creating an exception doesn't throw it.

Comment: @JB Nizet I totally agree with you but however if I write doThrow(new Exception()) instead of doThrow(Exception.class), I have the following error when I launch my test ; Expected exception com.company.project.exception.ElementNotFoundException but got org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:

Comment: doThrow(new Exception()).when(object).voidMethod(any());

Answer (score 50):

If you ever wondered how to do it using the new BDD style of Mockito:

```
willThrow(new Exception()).given(mockedObject).methodReturningVoid(...));
```

And for future reference one may need to throw exception and then do nothing:

```
willThrow(new Exception()).willDoNothing().given(mockedObject).methodReturningVoid(...));
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this here;

if the method returns a value :

given(mockedObject.methodReturningAnObject()).willThrow(new Exception());

if the method doesn't return anything :

willThrow(new Exception()).given(mockedObject).methodReturningVoid(...));

Explanation form javadoc : "Stubbing voids requires different approach from {@link Mockito#when(Object)} (or BDDMockito.given)because the compiler does not like void methods inside brackets..."

Answer (score 5):

I was having a issue trying to test @Retryable with three method calls when runtime exception occurred, I made like so and worked for me.

```
     Mockito.doThrow(RuntimeException.class)
            .doThrow(RuntimeException.class)
            .doNothing()
            .when(youMockInstance)
            .methodToTest(<parameter if your method has>);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try something like the below:

```
 given(class.method()).willAnswer(invocation -> {
          throw new ExceptionClassName();
        });
```

In my case, I wanted to throw an explicit exception for a try block,my method block was something like below

```
     public boolean methodName(param) throws SomeException{
    
        try(FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(param.getOutputFile())) {
          //some implementation
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
          throw new SomeException(ioException.getMessage());
        } catch (SomeException someException) {
          throw new SomeException (someException.getMessage());
        } catch (SomeOtherException someOtherException) {
          throw new SomeException (someOtherException.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
      }
```

I have covered all the above exceptions for sonar coverage like below

```
   given(new FileOutputStream(fileInfo.getOutputFile())).willAnswer(invocation -> {
      throw new IOException();
    });
    Assertions.assertThrows(SomeException.class, () ->
    {
      ClassName.methodName(param);
    });
```

Comment: `given(class.method())` gives the same error. Your `methodName` returns a boolean, while OP explicitly required it to return void