# The method when(T) in the type Stubber is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Tags: java, mockito

I am getting following error when stubbing a void:

> The method when(T) in the type Stubber is not applicable for the
>   arguments (void)

Here is my sample code:

```
doNothing().when(mockRegistrationPeristImpl.create(any(Registration.class)));

public void create(final T record) throws DataAccessException {
    try {
        entityManager.persist(record);
        entityManager.flush();
    } catch (PersistenceException ex) {}
}
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mockito test a void method throws an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156857/mockito-test-a-void-method-throws-an-exception)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your brackets are in the wrong place, try this:

```
doNothing().when(mockRegistrationPeristImpl).create(any(Registration.class));
```