# Unit test: Simulate a timeout with Guzzle 5

Tags: php, unit-testing, exception, timeout, guzzle

I am using **Guzzle 5.3** and want to test that my client throws a `TimeOutException`.

Then, how can I do a mock of Guzzle Client that throw a `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException`?

Code to test.

```
public function request($namedRoute, $data = [])
{
    try {
        /** @noinspection PhpVoidFunctionResultUsedInspection */
        /** @var \GuzzleHttp\Message\ResponseInterface $response */
        $response =  $this->httpClient->post($path, ['body' => $requestData]);
    } catch (ConnectException $e) {
        throw new \Vendor\Client\TimeOutException();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

The right question was: how to throw a Exception with Guzzle 5? or, how to test a catch block with Guzzle 5?

Comment: If you know the server's execution timeout value, why not try introducing php sleep or usleep to force a waiting time for an operation to finish?

Comment: The time out is set in the `httpClient` with is created as well as the connection the server. I think it is not an good idea create/simulate a server when I have a mock of `httpClient` (Guzzle). Only have to know how throw a exception with this mock.

Comment: Ok,  understood. Sorry I can't be of more help here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can test code inside a `catch` block with help of the `addException` method in the `GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Mock` object.

This is the full test:

```
/**
 * @expectedException \Vendor\Client\Exceptions\TimeOutException
 */
public function testTimeOut()
{
    $mock = new \GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Mock();
    $mock->addException(
        new \GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException(
            'Time Out',
            new \GuzzleHttp\Message\Request('post', '/')
        )
    );

    $this->httpClient
        ->getEmitter()
        ->attach($mock);

    $this->client = new Client($this->config, $this->routing, $this->httpClient);

    $this->client->request('any_route');
}
```

In the unit test, I add the `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException` to the mock. After, I add the mock to the emitter and, finally, I call the method I want test, `request`.

Reference:

[Source Code](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/5.3/src/Subscriber/Mock.php#L117)

[Mockito test a void method throws an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156857/mockito-test-a-void-method-throws-an-exception)