# Mock/Stub a RuntimeException in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

In `School` class, I have a `start()` function which invokes another function `doTask()`:

```
pubic class School {
    public void start() {
       try {
         doTask();
       } catch(RuntimeException e) {
          handleException();
       }
    }
    private void doTask() {
      //Code which might throw RuntimeException
    }
}
```

I want to unit test `start()` with `RuntimeException`:

```
@Test
public void testStartWithException() {
  // How can I mock/stub mySchool.start() to throw RuntimeException?
  mySchool.start();
}
```

It is not easy for my implementation code to throw the `RuntimeException`, how can I make the test code to mock a RuntimeException & throw it?

(Besides pure JUnit, I am considering using [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), but not sure how to throw RuntimeException)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mockito test a void method throws an exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156857/mockito-test-a-void-method-throws-an-exception)

Comment: Why does doTask() throw an exception?  If it's because of bad inputs, just use bad inputs in the test.  If it's because of an interaction with a service that has an unexpected issue, you need to mock or stub out that service to make it throw an exception to simulate the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Test
public void testStartWithException() {
  // How can I mock/stub mySchool.start() to throw RuntimeException?
  when(mySchool.start()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("runtime exception"));
}
```

You can use `when` with `thenThrow` to throw exception.

Comment: I don't think that start() is the method that is supposed to throw the exception.

Comment: I agree with above comment. I think the user is expecting the exception while executing doTask() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerMockito to mock the private method to throw a `RuntimeException`.  Something like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doThrow;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.spy;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(School.class)
public class SchoolTest {

    @Test
    public void testStartWithException() throws Exception {
        School school = spy(new School());

        doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(school, "doTask");    

        school.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks more like the answer that Leem.fin is looking for, but whenever you have to use Powermockito instead of Mockito, it may be a sign that the design could be improved.