# Java: Can I Inject a runtime exception into an arbitrary class method at runtime?

Tags: java, exception, runtime

For testing purposes, at times I'd like to see how my code handles having an unexpected runtime exception thrown, from various parts of the code.

For example, say I have a method like so:

```
public int getSum(int x, int y)
{
   return x + y;
}
```

Is there a way for me to cause this method to fail whenever it's called by throwing an exception instead of returning a valid result? I know I could add in explicit code to do this, but I'd like to know if it's possible to replace a method in *any* class with a new method that just throws an exception at runtime, or something like that ;-) Kind of like [how Mockito can do the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15157021/26510):

```
doThrow(new Exception()).when(mockedObject).methodReturningVoid(...);
```

I'd prefer any solutions to not require any extra tools - just the standard JVM. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want this during runtime?

Comment: Keep in mind that runtime exceptions are generally intended to communicate flat-out bugs in your software, such as not handling nulls properly. There's nothing in a method like this that should ever be expected to throw an exception, and I can't think of a good reason to simulate it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - My intent is to cause parts of our code to fail in unexpected ways. Kind of like a [Chaos Monkey](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Chaos-Monkey). I can't arbitrarily start adding code to throw random exceptions to key parts of our code, as I dont own all of it - i'm only on one team.... and other teams own major sections. But if I can fake their code failing at runtime in certain ways, from my own code base, then I can test out fail scenarios that they might not have thought of. And I do get that this could probably be done in unit tests, but there might be merit here

Comment: So this is really an integration test question.  You should create real world scenarios which cause these exceptions.  Other than this, stick to robust unit testing.  I agree with what @chrylis has said.

Comment: Yeah I'll admit I'm not 100% clear on how I'd ultimately use it, but the question itself still stands separately, regardless of how it's ultimately used ;-) Thanks!

Comment: The only thing you'd be simulating here is actual hardware failure or JVM bugs, which I don't expect you to be able to successfully handle at the individual-machine level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple purpose you could try using [Invocation Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) : wrap class method calls and throw exception if needed.

For more sophisticated manipulation you can use [Java Instrumentation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html).