# I want to write a mockito test case for a spring boot service method

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

This is the service method.

```
    @Override
    public void removeStudentByID(Long studentId) throws StudentExistsException {
        boolean exists = studentRepo.existsById(studentId);
        if (!exists) {
            throw new StudentExistsException("Student doesn't exist");
        }
        studentRepo.deleteById(studentId);
    }
```

Below is the test case I've written for it.

```
@Test
    public void removeStudentByIdTest() throws StudentExistsException {
        Student student = new Student(1, "Drake", "drake@gmail.com");
        when(studentRepo.save(student)).thenReturn(student);
        studentService.removeStudentByID(student.getId());
        assertEquals(false, studentRepo.existsById(student.getId()));
    }
```

It doesn't run...
But the below code works.

```
    public void removeStudent(String email) {
        Student student = studentRepo.findByEmail(email);
        studentRepo.delete(student);
    }
```

```
@Test
    public void removeStudentTest() throws StudentExistsException {
        Student student = new Student(3, "Ben", "ben@gmail.com");
        studentRepo.save(student);
        studentService.removeStudent(student.getEmail());
        assertEquals(false, studentRepo.existsById(student.getId()));
    }
```

So, being a noob, I'm kinda confused as to how to make it work in the first one. Or is something wrong with both of them.

Comment: hi! to test the top method, you would (correctly wire your mock, and then) `when(studentRepoMock.existsById()).thenReturn(false)` (in one test, `true` in another)...

Comment: ..when `false`: assert/expect exception, when `true`: `verify(studentRepoMock.deleteById(1)..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test this code:

```java
@Service
public class StudentService { 
  @Override
  public void removeStudentByID(Long studentId) throws StudentExistsException 
    boolean exists = studentRepo.existsById(studentId);
    if (!exists) {
        throw new StudentExistsException("Student doesn't exist");
    }
    studentRepo.deleteById(studentId);
  }
}
```

We can mock/"unit test" like this:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class StudenServiceTests { // we only test StudentService, since we (sort of) trust studentRepository (tested it elsewehere/how)

  @Mock // A Mock! (alternatively @MockBean)
  private StudentRepository studentRepoMock;
  @InjectMocks // A real service (with mocks injected;)!!! (alternatively @Autowired/...)
  private StudentService testee; // this guy we want to test (to the bone!)

  @Test // ..the "good case"
  void removeStudentByIdExists() throws StudentExistsException {
    // Given:
    // we don't even need a student, only his id
    // instruct mock for the "first interaction" (see testee code):
    when(studentRepoMock.existsById(1L)).thenReturn(true);
    // instruct mock for "second interaction" (see testee code):
    doNothing().when(studentRepoMock).deleteById(1L); // we could also use ...delete(any(Long.class))  or ..anyLong();

    // When: (do it!)
    testee.removeStudentByID(1L);

    // Then: Verify (interactions, with as exact as possible parameters ..Mockito.any***)
    verify(studentRepoMock).existsById(1L); //.times(n) ...when you had a list ;)
    verify(studentRepoMock).deleteById(1L);
  }

  @Test // .. the "bad (but correct) case"/exception
  void removeStudentByIdNotExists() throws StudentExistsException {
    // Given:
    when(studentRepoMock.existsById(1L)).thenReturn(false);

    // When:
    StudentExistsException thrown = assertThrows(
            StudentExistsException.class,
            () -> testee.removeStudentByID(1L),
            "Expected testee.removeStudentByID to throw, but it didn't");
    // Then:
    assertNotNull(thrown);
    assertTrue(thrown.getMessage().contains("Student doesn't exist"));
  }
}
```

... run with `mvn test`.

With these two test cases, *we achieve 100% test (& branch) coverage* for the given method/service.

---

But don't mix it up with "integration test" (where we use a real repo/data base), then we can use:

- [JDBC Testing Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-support-jdbc)
- [Test Annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations) (`@Commit, @Rollback, @Sql*`)
- JdbcTemplate
- ...

An sample on "default" (assuming empty) database, with preparation (and [`@Rollback`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-rollback)):

```java
package com.example.demo;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;

@SpringBootTest
class StudentServiceIT { // .. here we try to test "all of our application" (as good as possible ..to the bone)

  @Autowired //! real "bean", no mock... this is only auxilary for this test, we could use some other method to prepare & verify
  private StudentRepository studentRepository;
  @Autowired //!! "real service"
  private StudentService studentService;

  @Test
  @Rollback // actually our test is "self-cleaning"...when no exceptions ;)
  void removeStudentByIdExists() throws StudentExistsException {
    // Given:
    Student student = new Student(1L, "Drake", "drake@gmail.com");
    studentRepository.save(student);

    // When:
    studentService.removeStudentByID(1L);

    // Then:
    assertFalse(studentRepository.findById(1L).isPresent());
  }

  @Test
  @Rollback // in any case (if assumptions were wrong;)
  void removeStudentByIdNotExists() throws StudentExistsException {
    // Given:
    // nothing, we assume "empty db"

    // When:
    StudentExistsException thrown = assertThrows(
            StudentExistsException.class,
            () -> studentService.removeStudentByID(1L),
            "Expected testee.removeStudentByID to throw, but it didn't");
    // Then:
    assertNotNull(thrown);
    assertTrue(thrown.getMessage().contains("Student doesn't exist"));
  }
}
```

(Run with: `mvn failsafe:integration-test`)

Thanks to/Refs:

- [JUnit 5: How to assert an exception is thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40268446/592355)
- [Mockito test a void method throws an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15156857/592355)
- [Difference between @Mock and @InjectMocks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16467685/592355)

---

[Complete Sample@github](https://github.com/xerx593/soq70198317)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was struggling with this for two days. I'm very new to this. And even though I don't understand all aspects of your code, I promise I will get to the bottom of this, as I've already understood the gist of it. I can't thank you enough. No one else helped me.

Comment: welcome! (young:) "padawan" :) i add more comments (to code, in the post;)...

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it, lemme know if it's fine. :)

```
@Test
    public void removeStudentByIdTest() throws StudentExistsException {
        Student student = new Student(1, "Drake", "drake@gmail.com");
        when(studentRepo.existsById(student.getId())).thenReturn(true);
        studentService.removeStudentByID(student.getId());
        verify(studentRepo).deleteById((long) 1);
    }
```