# How to test a call is made to void method with nothing to assert inside that

Tags: java, junit, mockito, testcase

In the code below I have covered one of two branches of an if statement. But I also want to test the other branch, i.e. when `this.tom != null`.

```
public void setTom(boolean cmsConsent, boolean ebConsent) {
    if(this.tom== null){
        this.tom= new Tom(cmsConsent,ebConsent);
    }
}
```

How to write assert statement so that all branches are covered?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I unit test void functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219942/how-can-i-unit-test-void-functions)

Comment: As I have Stated, I have tested for that branch @MarkoTopolnik So next time I have exclude this branch :)

Comment: It would be helpfull to see how your test for that branch looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your field "tom" is a simple private field?
If it doesn't get injected, you can't mock it to be or not to be null.

I guess you also have a Getter for that tom object?
If you would change your code from:

```
if(this.tom== null){
```

to

```
if(this.getTom() == null){
```

than you could mock the Getter away using Mockito's SPY functionality.
(If you are willing to do so I can explain further)

PS: PowerMock(ito) is always a possibility to enhance your code by byte manipulation, but it should only be used when necessary imo.

Comment: It seems that it will work for me but I dont think that's a good practice  to add dependency as we bought "this.getTom()" in out test code., Which will call getTom() so thus it is depended on another method to run :|

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `setTom` directly from your test? If so, you don't assert that all branches are covered, you just test all branches via your knowledge of the code. Call `setTom` twice, once with `tom==null` and once with `tom != null`. Branches covered.

Comment: I don't think that by method stated by you will work ,As you told it seems to be i m just accesing the branches to increase my test coverage but I m not checking the bussiness code inside !