# How to mock void methods and retieve list results

Tags: java, junit, mockito, jmockit

```
  public void SomeClass {
       public void process() {
       mylist.addAll(rpp.getFilePaths(id));
       }
  }


    public class Test {

    @Test
        public void testProcess() throws Exception {  
         // I need help here ... 
        List <Path> results = when(rpp.getFilePaths(id)).thenReturn)(blah blah);
        test.process();
    }

}
```

With `Mockito`, how can I obtain the values of `mylist` when `test.process()` is called or how can I obtain the `List` that was returned when `rpp.getFilePaths(id)` was called.

Comment: Similar and answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-make-mock-to-void-methods-with-mockito

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
List<Path> results = new ....;
doReturn(results).when(rpp).getFilePaths(id);
```