# Stub void method using mockito

Tags: mockito, void, stub

I have an object whose method functionality I want to replace by just incrementing a counter when its called. The method has a `void` return type though, so I've been looking into how to stub void methods using mockito, but have not found a solution that works. From what I read I thought I could do something like this:

```
int count = 0;
Mockito.doReturn(++count).when(mockObject).mockObjectMethod(Mockito.anyString());
```

When I run this, I get

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.CannotStubVoidMethodWithReturnValue

So I believe I found two solutions: use `doThrow`, where I could catch the exception and increment the counter OR use `toAnswer` and increment the counter in the implementation of the `Answer`. Are there other solutions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-make-mock-to-void-methods-with-mockito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doThrow` is a really unconventional way to handle this, and I very much recommend against it—especially because it's an unusual code path, and one that will prevent the rest of your method-under-test from working after the thrown exception.

`doAnswer` is a much more appropriate way to make arbitrary behavior happen as the result of a void method, including counting.

However, if the purpose of the counter is to simply ensure that a method is called an exact number of times, then you don't want stubbing at all; Mockito's default for void methods is to do nothing except for recording the invocation, which is fine for this case. Instead, use verification:

```
verify(mockObject, times(EXPECTED_COUNT)).mockObjectMethod(anyString());
```

---

As a side note, be very careful not to confuse this:

```
doReturn(++count).when(mockObject).mockObjectMethod(Mockito.anyString());
```

with (hypothetical) syntax like this:

```
doReturn(() -> ++count).when(mockObject).mockObjectMethod(Mockito.anyString());
//       ^---lambda--^
```

Other than with Mockito matchers (through really counterintuitive hacks), Mockito doesn't get special treatment in its Java syntax. If `count = 0` and you run what you have, then this is exactly and only what Mockito will see:

```
doReturn(1).when(mockObject).mockObjectMethod(Mockito.anyString());
```

Comment: Using `verify` makes sense, but I don't want the mock object's method body to be executed. I just want to count the number of times its invoked, but do nothing else. Can I combine `verify` with `doNothing`?

Comment: @user1491636 Absolutely. Erase the existing behavior with `doNothing` and then `verify` the method call count later on. Sorry not to catch that the first time!