# Mockito: mocking objects and adding to ArrayList

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am testing an enterprise level application using Mockito and JUnit. Here is the code for a method of adding a product to the offline repository class in a product offline-repository-class-test I have:

```
@Mock
private InitialData initialData;

@InjectMocks
private ProductRepositoryOffline pro;

@Test
public void testPersistProduct() {
    Product product = new Product(0, "", "", "", 0.0, true, "", 0, /*Product type*/null, "", 0, 0);
    ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();    
    //productList.add(product);

    Mockito.when(initialData.getProducts()).thenReturn(productList);
    pro.persistProduct(product);
    assertEquals(pro.getProducts().get(0), product);
}
```

This relies on the following methods in classes:

The method it is testing in the `ProductRepositoryOffline`:

```
@Override
public void persistProduct(Product pr) {
    initialData.addProduct(pr);

}
```

InitialData

```
private ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

public void addProduct(Product product) {
    products.add(product);
}
```

The question I wish to ask is that in the case of `pro.persistProduct(product)` unless I have product already added to the `ArrayList`, isn't `persistProduct` meant to be adding product to the arrayList without the need for the commented `productList.add(product)`?

Comment: You've only declared what the mock of `initialData` does in the method `getProducts`, which I assume `ProductRepositoryOffline ` calls in it's version of `getProducts()`. What should `initialData.addProduct(pr)` do? At the moment, it does nothing

Comment: The problem is that you can't define the Mockito to add an object to a specific list when a method is called, it doesn't work that way. So unless you do `productList.add(product);`, the item of `product ` would never be added to the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what you should be doing:

```
@Mock
private InitialData initialData;

@InjectMocks
private ProductRepositoryOffline pro;

@Test
public void testPersistProduct() {
    Product product = new Product(0, "", "", "", 0.0, true, "", 0,
        /*Product type*/null, "", 0, 0);
    ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();    
    productList.add(product);

    Mockito.when(initialData.getProducts()).thenReturn(productList);
    pro.persistProduct(product);
    assertEquals(pro.getProducts().get(0), product);
    Mockito.verify(initialData).addProduct(product);
}
```

Because the object `initialData` is mocked, when it calls the method `initialData.addProduct(pr);` in your `ProductRepositoryOffline`, it does nothing. You have to manually add it to the list for checking later in your `assertEquals()`. To confirm the method was called though, you can use the `verify()` method to check that the `addProduct()` was called once on your mock object using the object of `product` you created. You can see more examples of `verify()` [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mockito/mockito-verify-example/)

There are other methods to mock void methods, like your usage of `addProduct()`, to see some examples of those, see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-make-mock-to-void-methods-with-mockito)

**[EDIT]**
Another variation you could do is to use the `doAnswer()`, which would look something like this:

```
Mockito.doAnswer(productList.add(product)).when(initialData).addProduct(product);
```

I'm not 100% this will work, as I have never used it, but I believe that at the point `initialData.addProduct(product);` is called, then the product will be added to your product list. That way you wouldn't need to use `productList.add(product);` Hope that helps a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved a similar problem in Scala.

I have a method with the following prototype:

```
def myMethod(x: Seq[Int]): Seq[MyStruct]
```

This method applies to each element in `x` a function. The result of this function depends on the value of the input. Hence, I would like to mock this method in my tests so that it may represent the real life with a pre-made mapping.

Here is how I mocked my function in my test class:

```
  when(objMock.myMethod(any())).thenAnswer({
    new Answer[Seq[MyStruct]] {
      override def answer(invocation: InvocationOnMock): Seq[MyStruct] =
        invocation.getArgumentAt[Seq[Int]](0, classOf[Seq[Int]]).map(myPremadeMapping)
    }
  })
```

With my premade mapping looking like this:

```
  val idToAudience = Map(
    param1 -> Ans1,
    param2 -> Ans2,
    param3 -> Ans3,
    ...
  )
```