# How to test a simple set method in Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

I’m trying to write mocking for to set a simple set in a class. I know that we do not need mocking for this specific example. But I'm using this example to learn how to use the framework. 
    class Test{
    Integer value;

```
public Integer getValue(){
    return this.value;
}

public void setValue(int val){
    this.value = val;
}

}
```

my mocking method looks like:

```
@Test
public void  testSetMethod(){
    Test v = Mockito.mock(Test.class);   
       Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(v).setValue(10);
         assertEquals(10,v.getValue());
}
```

I’m getting zero for v.getValue() in my assetEquals method instead of 10.

Comment: Why mocking at all? Why not simply test whether the `getValue` method returns the value that you provided in the `setValue` method one step before?

Comment: I need mocking for a more complicated scenario. But I'm just trying to learn how to use the framework.

Comment: Then unfortunately your example is not well crafted. Please use your real scenario and reduce it to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Additionally, you should not ask on how to use a framework at SO. There are plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: I'm not asking how to use the framework!!!! 
I said I'm learning how to use the framework.

Comment: @MIKE your setValue does not return anything. Assuming that the method is void, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-make-mock-to-void-methods-with-mockito on how to mock void methods and if it is to return Integer then ```when(v.setValue(10)).thenReturn(new Integer(10));```

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(v).setValue(10);
```

tells to call the real method when that method is called with that value.

So you have to call

```
v.setValue(10);
```

After that you would also have to add

```
 Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(v).getValue();
```

to make your example work.