# Unit testing void methods in Java Junit/Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I see similar questions, but not answered properly as I am looking for.

I have void method, which does some changes to the Model object as per the some other DB Values then save it again back to DB.

Pseudo code:

```
User{
List<Mark> marks;
String fullName;
int grade;
date dob;
}
```

The logic is to update User grade by applying some formulas by calling another service.

This is how I designed to test it:

I can give the `User` object with marks as input. I will mock the Service by providing the formula to determine the grades as per the marks. I want to test the final `User` Object is matching with what I am expecting just before saving.

I know that I can move that to separate method and return the object so that can be unit tested. What I am looking here is if there any way to test the logic inside a void method to verify the updated object. I have several methods like that in our project.

I know there is `Mockito.verify` or I can call like `doNothing` etc. This is just to call method and see what is happening inside. But I am not getting no data verification is possible by calling those methods.

It could be great if any one can suggest a solution for this.

I gave an example what the code is available for me. This is generic question though. My question is here how can I test a void method? My question is not how to mock a void method. Since void method does not return anything, but it does some logic and finally it updates DB. I want to test whether the implemented logic is working for different scenarios. The situation is cannot change the original method-writing a unit testing for those methods. Any suggestions?

Comment: "_I know that I can move that to separate method and return the object so that can be unit tested._"  <-- Do this.

Comment: Thanks @jaco0646 for your quick response. But you mean there is no way to verify the data inside a void method in java unit-testing?

Comment: I'm not saying you _can't_. I'm saying you _shouldn't_. Don't hack around the design problem with complicated testing. Fix the design.

Comment: You should provide an example. It's hard to tell what you're describing. I will say this:  _**"providing the formula ... I want to test the final User Object is matching with what I am expecting just before saving."**_ sounds like bad test design. Your test shouldn't care about the implementation of the web service, just that it gets invoked.

Comment: I read your posting 3 times; and I have no clue. What is the point of giving us explanations about what you think your code is doing; to then ask how to fix that code?! Come up with a [mcve]; and then we can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make mock to void methods with mockito](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-make-mock-to-void-methods-with-mockito)

Comment: Tnx guys, I edited my question, is there any way to test a void method? Or  any method with void return type cannot be tested? As per my understanding mocking and testing are two things. I want to do unit testing of a void method. What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact your method doesn't return anything is irrelevant. You test a void method same as any other method: setup your inputs, invoke the method, perform required assertions.

If I understand correctly, the issue you are experiencing is that the method does not return anything but as you are passing in the initial `User` object you already have a reference to the object so you can still perform whatever assertions you need to AFTER the void method completes.

Comment: Tnx, this resolves my problem now. I will need to read more about making better unit testable code. Do you have good reference to see more highlight on designing applications to make more unit testable...