# Mock test not returning any value Java Junit

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I am trying to test a method that connects to db using hibernate using junit and mocking.
Here is my code

***UserDAO.java***

```
public interface UserDAO {    
    public void addUser(String username, String password);
    public List<String> getUsers();
}
```

***UserDAOImpl.java***

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDAOImpl.class);
    private static Session session;

    public UserDAOImpl() {      
    }

   public UserDAOImpl(Session session) {
     this.session = session;
   }
    private static void beginSession() {
        session = DbUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(String username, String password) {
        String encryptedPassword = Utils.encrypt(password);
        User user = new User(username, encryptedPassword);
        beginSession();
        try {
            session.save(user);
            System.out.println(user.getPassword());
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (SQLGrammarException e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            LOG.error("Cannot save user", e);
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getUsers() {
        beginSession();
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        String hql = "select username from User";
        Query query = null;
        try {
            query = session.createQuery(hql);
            results = query.list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            LOG.error("Cannot execute query", e);
        } 
        return results;
    }
}
```

***TestUserDAOImpl***

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestUserDAOImpl {

    @Mock
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Mock 
    Session session;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
      when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
        // userDAOImpl = new UserDAOImpl(session);
        UserDAOImpl userDAOImpl = Mockito.mock(UserDAOImpl.class);
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        userDAOImpl.addUser(username, password);
        System.out.println(userDAOImpl.getUsers());
    }
}
```

The test case adds a set of username and password to the db but when I try to return the results using `getUsers()` it returns a null list.

Can anyone please help me fix this?

Comment: Start with the fact that your `addUser` method never gets called in your real object, because you're using the Mockito version.

Comment: How can I fix this? Even if the addUser method is called in real object it should not corrupt the main database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you are not adding any users to the DB, because `userDAOImpl` is a mocked object, therefore, as *Joe C* has pointed out, the `addUser` method never gets called on a real object. For the same reason (`userDAOImpl` is mocked) the `getUsers` method doesn't return any list.

Just as you have told `sessionFactory` what to do then its `getCurrentSession()` method is called, you can tell `userDAOImpl` what to do when its methods `addUser` and `getUsers` get called.

***As a side note***: the `testCreate()` method should not contain a `System.out.println` method, because `JUnit` cannot know whether your test should pass or fail. If you are using `Mockito`, you can use the `verify` method to make sure certain lines of code are getting executed.

Alternatively, if you want to test your repository, you can use an in-memory database and create real objects to insert data into and read from the database. This way your main database doesn't get polluted with test data. Here's a good [article](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/InMemoryTestDatabase.html) on in-memory test databases.

---

**UPDATE**: *Testing the `UserDAOImpl` class using Mockito*

The first thing I did is, changed the `UserDAOImpl` class a bit. The reason being: you can't mock static methods using `Mockito` (at least not at the moment of writing this post). More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito).

I'm passing the `session` object to `UserDAOImpl` and using that session to begin the transaction, instead of using the static method of `DbUtils`.

Here's the modified `UserDAOImpl` class:

```
package test.mockito;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDAOImpl.class);
    private Session session;

    public UserDAOImpl(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(String username, String password) {
        String encryptedPassword = Utils.encrypt(password);
        User user = new User(username, encryptedPassword);
        session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            session.save(user);
            System.out.println(user.getPassword());
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (SQLGrammarException e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            if(LOG != null)LOG.error("Cannot save user", e);
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getUsers() {
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        String hql = "select username from User";
        Query query = null;
        try {
            query = session.createQuery(hql);
            results = query.list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if(LOG != null)LOG.error("Cannot execute query", e);
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Let's see how you can test the methods of `UserDAOImpl` using mocked objects. Initially, we mock objects that we are not testing, but we need them in order to execute statements of the code under test.

```
package test.mockito;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doThrow;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.never;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserDAOImplTest {

    @Mock
    Session session;

    @Mock
    Transaction transaction;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(session.getTransaction()).thenReturn(transaction);
    }

    @Test
    public void addUserTest() {
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAOImpl(session);
        userDAO.addUser("testusername", "testpassword");
        try {
            verify(session).getTransaction();
            verify(session.getTransaction()).commit();
        } catch (SQLGrammarException e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }
        verify(session).close();
    }
}
```

**Note**: we are not testing `Session`, neither are we testing `Transaction`; therefore we are providing these objects to our `UserDAOImpl` class using `Mockito`. We assume that methods `save(User user)`, `commit()`, and other methods of mocked objects, are working properly, so we only test the `addUser` method. Using `Mockito` we don't need to establish a real session to the database, but mock the object instead, which is much easier and faster (moreover, it makes it possible to test the `addUser` method even if we haven't developed yet the other parts of the code - some other developer may be working on that).

In the test case above, the `addUserTest()` method, tests if this method executes properly when the methods of mocked objects behave as they are expected to. By using `verify(session.getTransacion()).commit()` we make sure that the `commit()` method is called, otherwise in the `catch` block the test fails.

In the same way we can test if `addUser` rolls the transaction back when an exception is thrown. Here's how you can do it:

```
@Test
public void addUserTestFails() {
    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAOImpl(session);
    try {
        doThrow(new SQLGrammarException()).when(session).save(any());
        userDAO.addUser("testusername", "testpassword");
        verify(transaction, never()).commit();
    } catch (SQLGrammarException e) {
        verify(transaction).rollback();
    }
}
```

This test case, tests the `addUser` method if it behaves as excepted when there's an exception thrown while saving the changes. You simulate the exception by telling the mocked object to throw an exception when the `save` method is called using this piece of code `doThrow(new SQLGrammarException()).when(session).save(any());`, and then you make sure that the `commit()` method is never called using `verify(transaction, never()).commit();`. In the `catch` block you verify that the transaction is rolled back: `verify(transaction).rollback()`.

Here's the complete class that contains these two test cases:

```
package test.mockito;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doThrow;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.never;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserDAOImplTest {

    @Mock
    Session session;

    @Mock
    Transaction transaction;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(session.getTransaction()).thenReturn(transaction);
    }

    @Test
    public void addUserTest() {
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAOImpl(session);
        userDAO.addUser("testusername", "testpassword");
        try {
            verify(session).getTransaction();
            verify(session.getTransaction()).commit();
        } catch (SQLGrammarException e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }
        verify(session).close();
    }

    @Test
    public void addUserTestFails() {
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAOImpl(session);
        try {
            doThrow(new SQLGrammarException()).when(session).save(any());
            userDAO.addUser("testusername", "testpassword");
            verify(transaction, never()).commit();
        } catch (SQLGrammarException e) {
            verify(transaction).rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I tell userDAOImpl what to do when addUser and getUsers gets called. `when(userDAOImpl.addUser(username, password).thenReturns("")` actually throws compile errors.

Comment: What is it that you want to test? If you want to test a specific method, then it should not be stubbed. You call that method on a real object, but you mock only objects that that method needs and you cannot provide at run-time while testing, for example session , some db connection etc.

Comment: If you need to mock void methods, have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-make-mock-to-void-methods-with-mockito).

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: step back. Now.

There is no point in using JUnit and Mockito for testing hibernate and DOAs ... when you lack the basic understanding **how** to write unit tests in the first place. In your code:

```
@Test
public void testCreate() {
  // userDAOImpl = new UserDAOImpl(session);
  UserDAOImpl userDAOImpl = Mockito.mock(UserDAOImpl.class);
  String username = "username";
  String password = "password";
  userDAOImpl.addUser(username, password);
  System.out.println(userDAOImpl.getUsers());
}
```

almost nothing makes sense. A typical unit test goes more like:

```
class UnderTest {
  Foo foo;
  UnderTest(Foo foo) { this.foo = foo; }

  int bar(String whatever) { return foo.bar(whatever); }
}

class UnderTestTest {
  @Mock
  Foo foo;

  UnderTest underTest;

  @Before
  public void setup() { underTest = new UnderTest(foo); }

  @Test
  public void testBar() {
    when(foo.bar(any()).thenReturn(5);
    assertThat(underTest.bar(), is(5);
  }
}
```

Notes:

- You don't mock the class you intend to **test**. You mock those objects that your class under test **needs** to do its job; but then, you still mock only those objects that you **have** to mock to make the test pass.
- You then call a method on your object under test; and you either **assert** that some expected result comes back; or you using mock **verification** to check that the expected calls on your mocked objects took place.

Long story short: you should rather spent a few days reading tutorials about JUnit and Mockito. In other words: learn to crawl before going for the hurdle race!