# Unable to write Mockito test case for my void method

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I need to test this code with Mockito (JUnit):

```
public class Calculation {

    public void logTimeTaken(String label, long estimatedTime, int size, boolean isDebug) {
       String out = label + " took " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(estimatedTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) + " milliseconds for " + size + " events!";
        if (isDebug) {
            System.out.println(out);
        } else {
            System.out.println(out);
        }
    }
}
```

I search so many examples google but still not getting any idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make mock to void methods with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-make-mock-to-void-methods-with-mockito)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure `System` with an instance of `PrintStream` which you can then assert against after invoking `Calculation.logTimeTaken`.

Here's an example:

```
@Test
public void canLogTimeTaken() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(bout);
    System.setOut(out);

    Calculation sut = new Calculation();
    sut.logTimeTaken("label", 20 , 2, false);
    assertEquals("if isDebug is false label took 0 milliseconds for 2 events!\n", bout.toString());
}
```

Note: there is no need for Mockito here, this is just vanilla JUnit, no mocking.

**But**, it might be a better design to refactor `logTimeTaken` into two distinct aspects:

- Deriving the log message
- Logging that message

For example:

```
public String createTimeTakenMessage(String label, long estimatedTime, int size, boolean isDebug) {
    return label + " took " + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(estimatedTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) + " milliseconds for " + size + " events!";
}

public void logTimeTaken(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

Then testing `createTimeTakenMessage` is trivial and you might even choose not to test `logTimeTaken` at all since all it does is invoke a System method. Or, perhaps you would hide the 'log action' behind an interface with an implementation using `System.out` now and perhaps, later, other implementations using a formal logging framework such as Logback.

Comment: glyching,I used your code and run the program but my test is failed showing actual and excpected different,maually I checked spaces and spellings also but still test is failed can you help me how to solve this..