# Cannot apply when mocking spring repository delete with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I googled all I could think of for solutions, but phrasing is difficult.

I have a unit test that calls delete on a Spring Repository. The repo is defined as:

```
public interface FileConfigurationRepository extends CasenetRepository<FileConfiguration, String> {}
```

The method I'm testing has the following call:

```
    fileConfigurationRepository.delete(GlobalConfiguration.CUSTOM_LOGO_ID);
```

Where GlobalConfiguration.CUSTOM_LOGO_ID is defined as:

```
public static final String CUSTOM_LOGO_ID = "customLogoId";
```

So I wrote my mock as follows:

```
  Mockito.when(fileConfigurationRepository.delete(GlobalConfiguration.CUSTOM_LOGO_ID)).thenThrow(new Exception());
```

But then I get the following error:

[image]

The text of the error:

```
No instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that void conforms to T
```

Unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Please paste the text of error, image is not visible behind firewall.

Comment: `Exception` is a checked exception. Unless your `delete() ` method declares `throws Exception`, you can't throw it from there. Use `RuntimeException`

Comment: @Arkadiy switched to RuntimeException. No change.

Comment: OK, then I need to see the text of the error. Image is filtered out :(

Comment: @Arkadiy Added. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Ah! it's `void delete(...)`, isn't it?  Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-make-mock-to-void-methods-with-mockito

Comment: @Arkadiy That was it, thanks! Can you post this as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As indicated, the issue was really about the return being void and not about the parameter type being passed. According to [How to make mock to void methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-make-mock-to-void-methods-with-mockito), I changed the code as follows:

```
    Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(fileConfigurationRepository).delete(GlobalConfiguration.CUSTOM_LOGO_ID);
```

And that fixed the problem.