# JUnit test for my method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Hello every one I need to write unit tests for my methods. I'm having a bit of trouble because I'm new to JUnit. I need to write a test for this method.
this is my method

```
@Override
public Long countSellingOrdersInQueue(String principal) {
    List<String> states = Arrays.asList(PENDING.name(), REGULARIZED.name());
    return orderRepository.countByArticleUserIdAndStateIn(principal, states);
}
```

I try but i'm blocked and this is my result

P.S. test is passed but I don't understand if my test is true

```
@MockBean
private OrderRepository orderRepository;

private String principal ;

@Test
public void countSellingOrdersInQueueTest(){
    orderService.countSellingOrdersInQueue(principal);
    List<String> states = Arrays.asList(PENDING.name(), REGULARIZED.name());
    orderRepository.countByUserIdAndStateIn(principal,states);
}
```

Comment: Why are you duplicating the code of the method under test in the test? It would be unbelievably brittle if you actually had to do this: what if you change the code but not the test? The test should invoke the method itself.

Comment: hello Andy thank you for your comment :) 
so what's the perfect solution ?

Comment: You clearly have some basic gaps in your understanding of writing unit tests. I would suggest that you spend time working through some tutorials before worrying about "perfect solutions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, it is just the unit test, you need not use @MockBean, as it loads the context. Unit tests are meant to be run faster, using @MockBean, will load the context and takes time to complete the test. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44200907/967808) is the suggestion of when to use @Mock and when to use @MockBean.

As Maxim said, there were no assertions in the test. That was the reason why the tests weren't failing.

Few things to keep in mind while writing the test.

- Tests are considered as documentation for the code, it should be more readable in such a way it makes others to understand the code.
- As said before, unit tests are for giving faster feedback
- Have AAA (Arrange, Act, Assert) structure in tests. More info [here](https://medium.com/@pjbgf/title-testing-code-ocd-and-the-aaa-pattern-df453975ab80)

Here is the code:

```
public class OrderServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Mock
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void countSellingOrdersInQueueTest(){
        when(orderRepository.countByArticleUserIdAndStateIn(any(), any())).thenReturn(1L);
        String principal = "dummyString";

        Long actualCount = orderService.countSellingOrdersInQueue(principal);

        List<String> expectedStates = Arrays.asList("State 1", "State 2");
        assertThat(actualCount, is(1L));
        verify(orderRepository).countByArticleUserIdAndStateIn(principal, expectedStates);
    }
}
```

Comment: good answer! would be perfect when mentioning that *unit test verify **behavior**, not code*...

Comment: Thank you Timothy!! Sorry, couldn't get your point actually. Could you please explain bit more. Will update accordingly

Comment: Please refer to this answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51153233/7023245 hope that makes it clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Test passes because you don't have any assertion, which checks result. You just invoke methods which executes without exception.

Simple test example:

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(true, true);
    }
```

In your case test will be look likes:

```
    @Test
    public void countSellingOrdersInQueueTest(){
        orderService.countSellingOrdersInQueue(principal);
        List<String> states = Arrays.asList(PENDING.name(), REGULARIZED.name());
        orderRepository.countByUserIdAndStateIn(principal,states);
        assertEquals(10, orderRepository.countByUserIdAndStateIn(principal,states));//10 replace to expectetion count
        //add some more checks
    }
```