# Mockito, mock class and real call void Methods

Tags: java, mockito

as the title suggests, the problem is this: I have the mock of `AdesioneMerger` and I have to call the real `merge` method. `merge` is a void method.

This is wrong:

```
adesioneMerger = Mockito.spy(AdesioneMerger.class);

Mockito.when(adesioneMerger.merge(
    Matchers.any(AdesioneBean.class),
    Matchers.any(Adesione.class), 
    Matchers.any(ServiceResultBean.class))
).ThenCallRealMethod();
```

what's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For void methods, use the alternative API:

```
Mockito.doCallRealMethod()
  .when(adesioneMerger).merge(
     Matchers.any(AdesioneBean.class),
     Matchers.any(Adesione.class), 
     Matchers.any(ServiceResultBean.class));
```

The problem is that `Mockito.when()` requires an argument (and there are no void-typed arguments in Java). The alternative API works around this by calling `when()` on the mock type and the actual method to mock is called on the return value of `when(...)`.

See also this answer: [How to make mock to void methods with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-make-mock-to-void-methods-with-mockito)

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
doCallRealMethod().when(adesioneMerger).merge(
    Matchers.any(AdesioneBean.class),
    Matchers.any(Adesione.class), 
    Matchers.any(ServiceResultBean.class);
```