# How to test void method

Tags: mockito, junit5

How do I test void method?

```
@Override
    public void insertUserDetails(String userData) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> userDataMap = jsonUtil.convertJsonToMap(userData);
        dao.insertUserDetails(userDataMap);
    }
```

I have tried with many methods but i didn't get solution.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make mock to void methods with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-make-mock-to-void-methods-with-mockito)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@Test
    public void insertUserDetailsTest() throws JSONException{
        String userdata = "{\"name\":\"test1\",\"dept\":\"test1\",\"id\":1}";
        Mockito.doNothing().when(mdmdao).insertUserDetails(Mockito.anyMap());
        mdmserviceimpl.insertUserDetails(userdata);
        Mockito.verify(mdmdao,times(1)).insertUserDetails(Mockito.anyMap());
    }
```

Comment: What is the different beetveen this and the previous solution?

Comment: The solution u have provided contains thenreturn(...) but void methods actually do not return any values.so i have used doNothing(....).

Answer (score 1):

You can cover your lines with [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/).

**Example:**

```
@Mock
private Dao dao;

@Test
public void insertUserDetails() {

    when(jsonUtil.convertJsonToMap(any(UserData.class)).thenReturn(...);

    obj.insertUserDetails(...);

    verify(dao, times(1)).insertUserDetails(expected);
}
```