# Mocking a void method in the same class that is under test with mockito and junit5?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit5

i want to mock a void method in the same class that is under test with mockito.
i can do that for not void method with annotating test class with @Spy and then use below code to return data i want.

```
        willAnswer(arg -> arg.getArgument(0))
            .given(customerService)
            .saveCustomer(any(Customer.class));
```

but how can do that for void method.
(i already try willDoNothing().given() function)

this is my real method:

```
public void deleteCustomersByTenantId(TenantId tenantId) throws ThingsboardException {
    log.trace("Executing deleteCustomersByTenantId, tenantId [{}]", tenantId);
    Validator.validateId(tenantId, "Incorrect tenantId " + tenantId);
    customersByTenantRemover.removeEntities(tenantId, tenantId);
}

public void deleteCustomer(TenantId tenantId, CustomerId customerId) throws ThingsboardException {
    log.trace("Executing deleteCustomer [{}]", customerId);
    Validator.validateId(customerId, INCORRECT_CUSTOMER_ID + customerId);
    Customer customer = findCustomerById(tenantId, customerId);
    if (customer == null) {
        throw new IncorrectParameterException("Unable to delete non-existent customer.");
    }
    entityViewService.unassignCustomerEntityViews(customer.getTenantId(), customerId);
    assetService.unassignCustomerAssets(customer.getTenantId(), customerId);
    userService.deleteCustomerUsers(customer.getTenantId(), customerId);
    deleteEntityRelations(tenantId, customerId);
    entityGroupDao.deleteEntityGroupsByTenantIdAndCustomerId(customer.getTenantId(), customerId);
    customerDao.removeById(tenantId, customerId.getId());
}

private final PaginatedRemover<TenantId, Customer> customersByTenantRemover =
        new PaginatedRemover<>() {

            @Override
            protected PageData<Customer> findEntities(TenantId tenantId, TenantId id, PageLink pageLink) {
                return customerDao.findCustomersByTenantId(id.getId(), pageLink);
            }

            @Override
            protected void removeEntity(TenantId tenantId, Customer entity) throws ThingsboardException {
                deleteCustomer(tenantId, new CustomerId(entity.getUuidId()));
            }
        };
```

and this is the test:

```
void deleteCustomersByTenantId() throws ThingsboardException {
    //given
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setId(CUSTOMER_ID);
    customer.setTenantId(TENANT_ID);

    ArgumentCaptor<CustomerId> customerIdArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(CustomerId.class);

    var pageData = new PageData<>(Collections.singletonList(customer), 1 ,1 , false);

    given(customerDao.findCustomersByTenantId(any(UUID.class), any(PageLink.class)))
            .willReturn(pageData);
    doNothing()
            .when(customerService)
            .deleteCustomer(any(), any());

    //when
    customerService.deleteCustomersByTenantId(TENANT_ID);

    //then
    then(customerDao)
            .should(times(1))
            .findCustomersByTenantId(any(UUID.class), any(PageLink.class));
    then(customerService)
            .should(times(1))
            .deleteCustomer(any(TenantId.class), customerIdArgumentCaptor.capture());
    assertEquals(CUSTOMER_ID, customerIdArgumentCaptor.getValue());
}
```

this is the Mocks:

```
//other mocks...

@Mock
private RelationService relationService;

@Mock
private CustomerValidator customerValidator;

@InjectMocks
@Spy
private CustomerServiceImpl customerService;
```

every dependency is mock with @Mock.

Comment: Have you done MockitoAnnotations.initMocks() before test?

Comment: yes
i use annotations Mock on dependency and InjectMock and Spy on class under test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do nothing works for me. Just pay attention to the calling order

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

doNothing().when(yourMock).yourMethod(yourArgs);
```

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-mock-void-methods-with-mockito) treats a similar problem, using a spy to mock specific methods with static factories should work. I've seen people doing to reverse operation (Use a Mock and then call the real method in some specific cases), but never tried it personally..

Comment: I used this, but like the other, it calls the real method in class.

Comment: Check if the arguments passed are an exact match of what you provided in the mock parameters. 

An important question to ask yourself is why you need to mock a method from the class under test itself. It could potentially be a code design smell that needs segregation

Comment: Yes, they are the same. i even used any() for args

Comment: can you please provide a minimal working example?

Comment: i add methods to question

Comment: sorry i forgot to add some other method. 
now is complete

Comment: I updated my answer with a link from another thread. If you look at most voted comments you'll see others commenting that the static method combined with the spy are suitable. Can you include the mocks and spy definitions in the code above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238353/discussion-between-sobhan-nami-and-daniel-vilas-boas).