# How to test case class calling another case class in scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I have a case class as

```
case class First()  {
  def run()
    callSecondCaseClass()

  }
}
```

then I have another case class as:

```
case class callSecondCaseClass()  {
     // does some operation and return 

      }
```

here How do I test case class First such that I can stub callSecondCaseClass to return some dummy value.

```
FirstTest.scala
mockFirst = mock[First]
when(First.callSecondCaseClass).thenReturn(value)
```

is there some way I can achevice to stub case class call from the first case class?

Comment: Is this the exact code? There are a couple of things wrong before you can start testing it properly. 1/ don't run side effects or anything in the constructor of a case class, create a specific "run" or "init" method. 2/ use dependency injection to have an instance of `callSecondCaseClass` in the `First` one. In tests, you'll lock this injected instance. 3/ [use `do` methods to mock `Unit` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276271/how-to-mock-void-methods-with-mockito).

Comment: 4/ remember that unit test doesn't mean testing each and every method independently. The unit can be a whole feature traversing multiple layers/methods. Hard to say if this is applicable here but you have to mock and it's not easy to mock, if often mean you're trying to test internal implementation details rather than the functional result of a feature.

Comment: I'd add that: `case class`es, `sealed` hierarchies of `case class`es, primitives, lambdas, value classes and collections/`Option`s/`Either`s of all of the before, are examples of data. They can be easily created, should NOT store behavior (lambda can store, but, you now), can be trivially passed around and need no mocking. Lambdas can be created with language's syntax to do whatever you want, everything else has a constructor and can be compared with `==`.