# Abort test on super method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, super

I've got the following method

```
public void myMethod(final MyObject myObject) {
   if (myObject.isDownload()) {
      // Do something
   } else {
      super.myMethod();
   }
}
```

I want to verify now in a JUnit test, that the `super` implementation has been called.

I also want to abort the test, if the `super` call has been performed, since the underlying implementation is very complicated and hard to test respectively mock.

---

I'm using Mockito as a mocking framework.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a perfect use case for a mocking framework. Just mock your implementation of `super` in a way that it does nothing on a call to `myMethod()`. Verify that `myMethod()` was called on your mock in the unit test.

You could give [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) a try. But there are several other good mocking frameworks for Java.

Comment: How can I mock the super implementation of a concrete class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087339/using-mockito-to-test-abstract-classes

Comment: But how can I differentiate between my implementation and the `super` implementation?