# How should I test interfaces?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I have two really simple interfaces

```
public interface Decoder {
    public void decode() throws Exception;
}


public interface Encoder {
    public void Encode() throws Exception;
}
```

How can I test these two interfaces using mockito?

Comment: What do you want to test? There is nothing to test with an interface..

Comment: I have an encoding/decoding project that is meant to have 100% test coverage. I assume I am even being asked to test something as simple as interfaces.

Comment: @prodigylover: But an interface has no functionality.  There are no code paths to test.

Comment: You have to test the implementations of your interfaces. Or test the classes that have a field of type `Decoder`/`Encoder` and mock these interfaces. But not the interface itself, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel do you mind if I ask you something via your facebook account?

Comment: @prodigylover: I don't mind, but it might be better if you do it on [the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java) instead. Other people will be able to chime in then.

Comment: maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087339/using-mockito-to-test-abstract-classes http://www.rallydev.com/community/engineering/easy-way-test-abstract-classes-mockito http://www.java-producties.nl/testing/unit-testing-a-abstract-class-with-mockito/

Answer (score 1):

As Jeroen mentioned in the comments:

> What do you want to test? There is nothing to test with an interface.

Instead:

> You have to test the implementations of your interfaces. Or test the classes that have a field of type Decoder/Encoder and mock these interfaces. But not the interface itself, that doesn't make sense.