# Mocking spring IOC method injection's method

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

Is there any way to mock a method which is injected by spring container using method injection approach.

Let me explain in detail

I have abstract class called Singleton which has abstract method in it

```
public abstract class Singleton {

    protected abstract LoanField check();

    private LoanField getLoanField(String name) {

    LoanField field = check();

}
```

and it's corresponding configuration is there in one of the spring-config file.

```
<bean id="checkDetails" class="com.abc.tools.Singleton">
        <lookup-method name="check" bean="field"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="field" class="com.abc.tools.LoanField" scope="prototype"/>
```

Here is my test class in short

```
Singleton fieldManager = Mockito.mock(Singleton.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
LoanField loanField = PowerMockito.mock(LoanField.class);
PowerMockito.when(fieldManager.create()).thenReturn(loanField);
```

Actual problem here is, in Method Injection Spring overrides a given abstract method of an abstract class and provides an implementation of the overridden method but when i try to stub that method in my test class I'm getting below error

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.abc.tools.Singleton.create()Lcom/abc/tools/LoanField;
at com.abc.tools.SingletonTest.loanFiledNotNull(SingletonTest.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
at
```

i know its not possible to stub an abstract method but is there any work around to stub the method? Please help me out.

Ps: I mentioned all the depended class in `@preparefortest`

Comment: show your test code

Comment: @Nir Levy added test class code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Make dummy class that extends your abstravct class, add dummy implementation and test this class.

Answer (score 0):

Try with spy,

```
    Singleton s  = new Singleton(){

    private LoanField getLoanField(String name) {

        LoanField field = check();

    }

    protected LoanField check(){
       return new LoanField();
    }

    }

    Singleton fieldManager = spy(s);
    LoanField loanField = mock(LoanField.class);
    when(fieldManager.create()).thenReturn(loanField);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087339/using-mockito-to-test-abstract-classes

Answer (score 0):

If objects are created via method injection, then best approach is use below code snippet on top of your test code, the moment we run test case @contextconfiguration will create objects for abstract class and you will get hold on abstract methods as well.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({LoggerFactory.class,Class.class})
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/test/resources/META-INF/spring-config-test.xml")
public class TestClass {
```

Basically you should have test xml file which is same as actual xml file and load it using @contextConfiguration.

Thanks.