# Mockito 0 matchers expected 2 recorded

Tags: mockito, guava, jukito

I am getting weird exception for:

```
when(IMMUTABLE_TABLE_MOCK.get(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(true);
```

> InvalidUseOfMatchersException 0 matchers expected, 2 recorded

IMMUTABLE_TABLE_MOCK is  Guava's ImmutableTable : https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableTable.html

Comment: Please Add the IMMUTABLE_TABLE_MOCK.get method signature

Comment: Its Guava's ImmutableTable : https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableTable.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087339/using-mockito-to-test-abstract-classes

Comment: There is never a good reason to mock a collection or a collection type.  Make a real collection.