# Mocking an abstract method, but not the class constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a scenario where I have an abstract class similar to the below. I want to mock out the `RandomNumberGenerator` instance that is supplied via the constructor and I want to write a unit test to test the logic in the `doSomethingRandomLotsOfTimes` method.

Is there a way I can do this with mockito/another framework?

```
public abstract class MyClass {

    private final RandomNumberGenerator randomNumberGenerator;

    public MyClass(RandomNumberGenerator randomNumberGenerator) {
        this.randomNumberGenerator = randomNumberGenerator;
    }

    public abstract void doSomething(int x);

    public void doSomethingRandomLotsOfTimes() {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            int r = randomNumberGenerator.next();
            doSomething(r);
        }
    }
}
```

---

My Test

```
@Test
public void testItDoesSomething10Times() {
    // Given
    when(randomNumberGenerator.next()).thenReturn(0);
    MyClass myClass = ...

    // When
    myClass.doSomethingRandomLotsOfTimes();

    // Then
    // Assert Something
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087339/using-mockito-to-test-abstract-classes

Comment: @OleksandrShpota I think there's a difference as those questions dont involve a constructor parameter which needs to be mocked

Comment: Why do you need to mock this class? Use the real class, with a mocked RNG. Also, this looks like an example of where composition should be preferred to inheritance: `doSomething` is simply an [`IntConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntConsumer.html): pass one of those into the constructor instead. Then you can unit test the `IntConsumer`, and unit test that `MyClass` invokes the `IntConsumer`.

Comment: I'd rather keep the tests specific to logic in this class in a `MyClassTest` and let tests of sub classes only worry about the logic in themselves

Comment: *"I'd rather keep the tests specific to logic in this class"* this supports the *favor composition over inheritance* suggestion of Andy. Make thid a real class, give the Method `doSomethingRandomLotsOfTimes` a functional interface parameter and pass it as dependency to classes who need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class is much more readily implemented via composition:

```
public final class MyClass {

    private final RandomNumberGenerator randomNumberGenerator;
    private final IntConsumer somethingDoer;

    public MyClass(
            RandomNumberGenerator randomNumberGenerator,
            IntConsumer somethingDoer) {
        this.randomNumberGenerator = randomNumberGenerator;
        this.somethingDoer = somethingDoer;
    }

    public void doSomethingRandomLotsOfTimes() {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            int r = randomNumberGenerator.next();
            somethingDoer.consume(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can write a unit test to assert that `MyClass` works, and it calls the `somethingDoer` the expected number of times; and you can write unit tests to assert that your `IntConsumer`s work.

But you don't have to worry about things like:

- The fragile base class problem.
- Careless/malicious implementations of `MyClass` invoking `doSomethingRandomLotsOfTimes()` from `doSomething()` (well, maybe you do, it's just a lot harder...)
- "Designing and documenting for inheritance"

etc.

Comment: Thank you very much sir --- wishing you a nice evening, good night, and may the next days greet you with great questions to answer!

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to directly instantiate an abstract class.
You must instantiate a non-abstract class that extends the abstract class.

Declare a non-abstract class that extends the abstract class in the unit test class (for example `public static class blam extends MyClass`) and provide empty implementations of all abstract methods.

Once you have a class that you can instantiate,
create a spy of the RandomNumberGenerator class.
A spy allows you to test that methods in the spy are called.

Create an instance of `blam` and pass the spy RandomNumberGenerator as the constructor parameter.

Comment: I would quite like to test some scenarios of how the logic in MyClass handles doSomething() throwing exceptions etc, is this possible with the method you describe?

Comment: @Ed0906 sure, just implement the abstract method to throw an exception.

Comment: You can create a mock with: `MyClass myClass = mock(MyClass.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);`
To throw an exception: `doThrow(new Exception()).when(myClass).doSomething(anyInt());`

Comment: Once you have a spy, it is exactly like the mock with Calls_Real_methods that Hugo mentions.  With a spy, you can mock the individual methods and throw as you need.