# Unit Testing Concrete Methods in an Abstract Class

Tags: java, unit-testing, oop

Suppose I want to unit test the following abstract class:

```java
abstract class Fruit {

  private int calories;

  public Fruit(int calories) {
    this.calories = calories;
  }

  int getCalories() {
    return this.calories;
  }

  double getKilojoules() {
    return this.calories * 4.184;
  }
}
```

I agree that abstract classes and interfaces should not be tested - their implementations should, but what about concretely defined methods like simple getters like `getCalories()`?

Now some say that simple methods like getters should not be tested, but even then: what about methods like `getKilojoules()`?

Comment: create a stub implementation and test that.

Comment: Thanks. So basically mocking. I'm doing that now, but wasn't sure if it's the best way to go.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087339/using-mockito-to-test-abstract-classes