# Testing an abstract class with Mockito does not give the expected result

Tags: java, mockito, testng, abstract-class

I have a class structure similar to the following

```
 public abstract class AbstractStep {
     private final Range RANGE;

     AbstractStep(AbstractStepBuilder builder) {
          RANGE = builder.range;   
     }


      public abstract static class AbstractStepBuilder {
           Range range;

           public AbstractStepBuilder setRange(int start, end end) {
                this.range = new Range(start, end);
                return self();
           }

           abstract AbstractStepBuilder self();
      }

      public static class Range() {
           private final int START;
           private final int END;

           private Range(int start, int end) {
                if(start < 0 || end < 0 || start >= end)
                      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                START = start;
                END = end;
           }
      }
 }
```

I want to test `setRange(int, int)` in `AbstractStepBuilder` to see if the an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown. I use TestNG and Mockito, and I have attempted the following using with the help of [this](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-test-abstract-class).

```
 final class RangeTest {
      AbstractStepBuilder builder;

      @BeforeSuite 
      void setup() {
           builder = Mockito.mock(AbstractStepBuilder.class);
           Mockito.when(builder.self()).thenReturn(null);
       }

     @Test(expectedExceptions = IllegalArgumentException.class)
     final void testCreatingRangeWithNegativeStart() {
          builder.setRange(-1, 2);
     }
}
```

This test fails. I have also tried replacing `Mockito.mock(AbstractStepBuilder.class)` with `Mockito.mock(AbstractStepBuilder.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)` as in the top answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087339/using-mockito-to-test-abstract-classes) question.

Note that if I make `CodeRange` as its own outer class, this test passes, so I do not believe it could be the test itself.

Why is this test failing, and is it possible to fix it without having to use a concrete class in the test instead?

Comment: you don't call AbstractStepBuilder#setRange at all

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: @kofemann Fixed, sorry this way due to copying from a more complicated project

Comment: @ThomasMartin the test in `RangeTest` fails

Comment: "us it possible to fix it without having to use a concrete class in the test instead?" Concretely no because you cannot invoke an instance method on a concrete class. It has to be concrete.  Creating a minimal subclass in the test scope looks a correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling a method on a mock, that will never throw an Exception until you tell it to. You never mock a class you want to test.

If you want to test the actual class, you'll need to create a subclass of the step builder, create an instance and test that.

I think you can also create a spy (by `Mockito.spy(AbstractStepBuilder.class)`) to avoid creating a subclass just for the test.

Comment: @davidxxx Yeah but I was to lazy to find the section in the documentation advising against it :P Also, creating a subclass specifically for the test also has a code smell to me. So I guess it's a lesser of two evils situation.

Comment: Create a subclass for the test is not necessarily the best thing today either , I agree :) Maybe a path between them is possible :)

Comment: @davidxxx Maybe define a subclass and then create a spy of that... ;)

Comment: Is it not the worst of the two worlds ? No I think that you first idea is fine. Usually I don't try to test abstract classes because that is abstract. If I really need to do that because for example that is a class that I expose to other clients, creating a subclass in a test scope is not really a bad smell. Whatever you have my vote for the first point :)

Comment: @davidxxx yes, that was a joke.

Comment: I supposed that  but not sure :)