# Testing abstract class with Mockito. How?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following class:

```
abstract class Foo {
        abstract List<String> getItems();
        public void process() {
            getItems()
                    .stream()
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
```

What I'd like to test is the `process()` method, but it is dependent on the abstract `getItems()`. One solution can be to just create an ad-hoc mocked class that extends `Foo` and implements this `getItems()`.

What's the Mockito way to do that?

Comment: I would not *mock* `Foo` but create an inner class `FooTestImpl` in your `FooTest` class and use an instance of that for your test. You should of course not override any methods already implemented in the parent class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Mockito to test abstract classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087339/using-mockito-to-test-abstract-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just:

```
    List<String> cutsomList = ....
    Foo mock = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
    Mockito.when(mock.getItems()).thenReturn(customList);
    Mockito.when(mock.process()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Or (for void)

```
    doCallRealMethod().when(mock.process()).voidFunction();
```

Comment: Since I need to check the original method `process()`

Comment: @yaseco then just call the real method?

Comment: Oh I see what you did with `thenCallRealMethod()` thanks!