# How to replace abstract class? (composition instead of inheritance) - concrete problem

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

my problem started when I wanted to write unit test for an abstract class (test the common methods) than I discovered it would be probably better to prefer composition instead of inheritance (I can use mocks for the part which is changing "connection")

Now I have hard time to come up with some design which would be correct so could someone help me here?

Whole my code can be found [here](https://github.com/bzumik1/metalForming/tree/master/src/main/java/com/siemens/metal_forming/connection) but for simplicity I will try to describe it shortly here. I have class `PlcData` which represents current status of variables I need which are read from PLC. The `PlcData` represents subject in **observer pattern** and I subscribe to it with different classes (I also need to know what exact attribute has been changed that is why `PlcData` implements "source" interface for each attribute I need to observe, I also need to get all data when the attribute is changed because based on some other attributes I search in database - that is why I send whole `PlcData` when any attribute changes). I would like to keep the observers of `PlcData` independent on connection (how the `PlcData` reads/writes variables from PLC).

Here is my original design with abstract `PlcData`:[image: Current design]

I would like to achieve something like this (a lot of programmers confirmed me that this is the correct way) where the `PlcData` is concrete class (I could use also interface for it in future) and the connection is as attribute of `PlcData`:
[image: New design]

My problem is that I don't know how to correctly implement this. The each concrete class of "Connection" will use some library and will have a lot of specifics here but it should handle the subscription, read, write to those "important" variables (serialNumber, measuredCurve ... - in real code I have more of them but they are exactly given). But I would like this to be invisible for `PlcData` "user" so he would just call some factory method `PlcDataProvider.getPlcData()` and he would get instance of PlcData with initialised connection and he would just subscribe to variables he needs (or write to those variables and the `PlcData` class would handle how to send them to PLC over the "Connection" interface.

***MY BIGGEST PROBLEMS***

1. I don't know how to correctly make the `Connection` updating the `PlcData` and how to  write to real PLC variables over it (I am really lost here and I end up with three methods for each attribute (writeSerialNumber, readSerialNumber, subscribeToSerialNumber and the `Connection` needs to keep track of `PlcData`)
2. How to correctly create PlcData using some factory

Comment: It's not at all clear to me how the data flow is either before nor after. Maybe some sample code how a single data item is updated with all classes involved would help.

Comment: Strattegy is always kind of a weak pattern; I'd go for an adapter on those different sources, which could be used compositionally by `PicData`. As far as usage, the `PicData` shouldn't really know anything about the `Connection`, rather some intermediary class would serialize/handle sending the data for it over the connections.

Comment: @daniu Hi, I have provided link to the GitHub, there you can check how I am handling the data flow (IN CURRENT DESIGN) basically now the PlcDataOpcua handles also the connection so it keeps the data in PlcData up to date. So when I need to do something based on the change of some variable I subscribe to given variable. In my diagram for example the display would display all attributes of PlcData when ever the ConnectionStatus changes.

Comment: @Rogue do you mean to use adapter for connection? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @JakubZnamenáček no, the three `*Source` classes could be brought under a single adapter.

Comment: @Rogue could you give me an example how you would implement it, I am probably missing what it would help.

Answer (score 1):

Your new design will require a so called billateral association between `PlcData` and `Connection`, meaning both should hold references to each other. This is combersome.

Instead use the 'Replace bidirectional association with unidirectional' refactoring. That way only `PlcData` will know about `Connection`, but not vice versa.

`PlcData` is responsible for updating its own fields. `Connection` shouldn't know about this (it should only... connect). This means the `Connection#update*` methods belong to `PlcData`.

PS: Also this smells more like the `Bridge` pattern. `Strategy` enapculates algorithms and I am not sure this is the case here.