# PHPUnit: Method in mocked abstract class returns null

Tags: phpunit

I'm writing tests against the following class:

```
abstract class EmailMessageRecipient
{
    private $_address = null;

    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->_address = $address;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->_address;
    }

}
```

The test looks like this:

```
class EmailMessageRecipientTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $_test_object;

    protected function makeTestObject()
    {
        return $this->createMock(EmailMessageRecipient::class);
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->_test_object = $this->makeTestObject();
    }

    public function testAddress()
    {
        $this->_test_object->setAddress('blah@example.com');
        $this->assertEquals('blah@example.com', $this->_test_object->getAddress());
    }
}
```

PHPUnit fails the test with the message `Failed asserting that null matches expected 'blah@example.com'.`. So `$this->_test_object->getAddress()` is returning `null` instead of the email address that was passed to it. Why is this happening and how do I adjust the test so that it passes.

Mocking the `setAddress()` and `getAddress()` methods is not an acceptable answer. The purpose of this test is to cover `setAddress()` and `getAddress()`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/190295/457268

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you test an abstract class you should use: [getMockForAbstractClass](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html):

> The getMockForAbstractClass() method returns a mock object for an
>   abstract class. All abstract methods of the given abstract class are
>   mocked. This allows for testing the concrete methods of an abstract
>   class.
>
> #### Example 9.19: Testing the concrete methods of an abstract class
>
> ```
> <?php
> use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
>
> abstract class AbstractClass
> {
>     public function concreteMethod()
>     {
>         return $this->abstractMethod();
>     }
>
>     public abstract function abstractMethod();
> }
>
> class AbstractClassTest extends TestCase
> {
>     public function testConcreteMethod()
>     {
>         $stub = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(AbstractClass::class);
>
>         $stub->expects($this->any())
>              ->method('abstractMethod')
>              ->will($this->returnValue(true));
>
>         $this->assertTrue($stub->concreteMethod());
>     }
> }
> ?>
> ```